# invalid block-tag when I implement i18n

Tags: django

I'm currently adding i18n in my website but there is something wrong.

When I use code from [djangoproject](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view)

```
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
<select name="language">
{% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
{% for language in languages %}
<option value="{{ language.code }}">{{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

I get this error

> Invalid block tag: 'get_language_info_list'

I don't understand why `get_language_info_list` is unknown. Templates_context_processors is ok. HTML form is on my homepage.

Comment: Did you forget `{% load i18n %}`?

Comment: you're right Burhan, this is the right anwser, thank you :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Always make sure you load the tag library first before you requests any tags. To use `get_language_info_list`, you need to make sure `{% load i18n %}` is in your template.